# Why does increasing precision make this program faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I was solving problem 26 on Project Euler where I need to calculate the length of the recurring part of 1/n where n is all integers between 1 and 1000, and see which number makes the longest recurring part. That meant that I needed my division done a lot more precisely. So I was playing around with my decimal precision by changing `getContext().prec`, but then somehow increasing the accuracy made the program a lot faster. I ran this program using Python 3.7. Here is the code:

```
import re
import time
s = time.time()
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 500 #This part
recurring = 0
answer = 0
p = re.compile(r"([0-9]+?)\1{3,}")
for i in range(1, 1000):
    f = p.search(str(Decimal(1) / Decimal(i))[5:])
    if f:
        number = f.group(1)
        if len(str(number)) > len(str(recurring)):
            recurring = number
            answer = i

print(answer)
print(time.time() - s)
```

This was the result when I used precision of 500:

```
>>> print(answer)
349
>>> print(time.time() - s)
2.923844575881958
```

...and this is what I got when I used precision of 5000:

```
>>> print(answer)
983
>>> print(time.time() - s)
0.07812714576721191
```

I swapped 500 with 5000, and not only did it give me the correct answer since the recurring part of 1/answer was probably longer than 500, but it also was much faster. I have tried this with an online Python interpreter, and it also gave me similar result. Why is it like this?

Comment: FYI: I repeatedly executed your code on my local machine and got consistent results: `1.5804040432` for precision 500 and `1.96949100494` for 5000. The actual answer is the same as in your case. Can you tell which online python interpreter you used?

Comment: i get similar behaviour to here fwiw. 349 with `1.5289030075073242` and 983 with `0.09225702285766602` @MaxKapsecker im running using spyder on an anaconda install of python 3.6.

Comment: I got `349 ~ 1.40679907799` for precision of 500 and `983 ~ 2.08120393753` for precision of 5000, python 2.7.6 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @MaxKapsecker https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter

Comment: I have been using Python 2.7. Using Python 3.6 on my local machine got me the same results like @HerO_0110. Furthermore, it turned out that running the code on Python 2.7 with different values, e.g. 1000 and 5000, also showed inconsistency. `581 ~ 3.19620895386` for 1000 and `983 ~ 2.04031896591` for 5000.

Comment: The same works for `re.search(r"([a-z]+?)\1{3,}", string.ascii_lowercase*4)`. It is faster, if it finds a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is the combination of + and \1 in the regex

### Methods

I used the following test code:

```
import time
import re
import string
t=time.time()
re.compile() # I tried differend regexes here
print(time.time()-t)
def test(n):
    t=time.time()
    match = rex.search(string.ascii_lowercase*n)
    print(match, time.time()-t)
```

After restarting the python session, the first call to `re.compile` takes longer than subsequent compilations of the same regex.

```
                                        compile(sec)   search (sec)    
REGEX                                   1st     2nd    short   long string
r"(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz){6,}"     10^-4   10^-5  10^-5   10^-5
r"(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)\1\1\1\1" 10^-4   10^-5  10^-6   10^-6
r"([a-z]+?)\1\1\1\1"                    10^-4   10^-5  10^-4   10^-5 
r"([a-z]+)\1\1\1\1"                     10^-4   10^-5  10^-4   10^-5
r"([a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z])\1\1\1\1"
                                        10^-4  10^-5  10^-6  10^-6
```

Interestingly, occasionally `r"([a-z]+?)\1\1\1"` would be quick (10^-5 sec) for too short strings as well.

### Discussion

There is some caching involved in compiling the rexex, but this was not the reason here.

It seems that the combination of the `+` operator (both greedy and non-greedy) inside the group and the `\1` in the regex is at fault. For some reason, this combination is quicker if it actually matches than if it does not match.

To find out more, we probably have to understand the C source code of the `sre` module

Answer (score 1):

Something happens around prec == 4000. All answers are equal to 983, and time changes only slightly linearly from 4000 up. Maybe take a closer look there.

There is also a small dip around 2000. You need to measure separately time elapsed during Decimal divison and time elapsed during regex search to get more info.

On this image: prec (horizontal) vs. time in seconds (vertical)
[image: prec vs. time]

Comment: Profiling shows that it is the fault of `re.search`. Further more, most cases in the iteration up to 1000 are quick, but some special case take long. (e.g. for prec=2000, there are 27 cases that take 0.08 sec, while the rest is fast) These special cases disappear when prec>4000